# Populate dropdown depending on the value of an other dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a PHP form where a dropdown is populated with values from a database table.

```
$options_demande['orderBy'] = array('id_produit' => 'ASC');
    $options_demande['items'] = array('produit');
    $data['id_produit'] = $this->produit_model->getListCombo('*',null,$options_demande,'Sélectionner un produit');
$options_demande['orderBy'] = array('id_abonnement' => 'ASC');
    $options_demande['items'] = array('abonnement');
    $data['id_abonnement'] = $this->abonnement_model->getListCombo('*',null,$options_demande,'Sélectionner un abonnement');
```

The getListCombo method :

```
public function getListCombo($select = '*', $conditions = array(), $optional = null, $first_line = null)
{
    $dropdown = array();
    if ($select != null)
        $this->db->select($select)->from($this->table);

      if (isset($conditions['where']))
        $this->db->where($conditions['where']);

      if (isset($conditions['where_in']))
        $this->db->where_in($conditions['where_in']);

      if (isset($conditions['where_or']))
        $this->db->or_where($conditions['where_or']);

      if (isset($conditions['like']))
        $this->db->like($conditions['like']);

      if (isset($conditions['like_or']))
        $this->db->or_like($conditions['like_or']);

    if (isset($optional['orderBy']))
        foreach($optional['orderBy'] as $order => $val)
            $this->db->order_by($order,$val);

    $rs = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    if (isset($first_line))
    {
        if (is_array($first_line))
            $dropdown[$first_line['k']] = $first_line['v'];
        else
            $dropdown[''] = $first_line;
    }
    foreach($rs as $item){
        $liste = null;
        foreach($optional['items'] as $item_liste){
            $liste .= $item[$item_liste]." ";
            $dropdown[$item['id_' . $this->table]] = $liste;
        }
    }     

    return $dropdown;
}
```

The thing is that I want an other dropdown to be populated with specific values of an other table.

The code of my dropdown :

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="id_produit"><?php echo lang('produit'); ?><span class="required"> * </span></label>   
              <div class="col-md-4">
                 <?php echo form_dropdown('id_produit', $id_produit, null,'class="form-control" required="required"')?>
              </div>
           </div>
<div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="id_abonnement"><?php echo lang('abonnement'); ?><span class="required"> * </span></label>   
              <div class="col-md-4">
                 <?php echo form_dropdown('id_abonnement', $id_abonnement, null,'class="form-control" required="required"')?>
              </div>
           </div>
```

I think I have to use some javascript, but I don't know how to do that.

At the moment the other is populated with all the values of the other table, but I'd like for example that for a specific value of the first dropdown, the other is populated with the values of the other table where "type_abonnement" = 1. Or 2 for an other value.

[image: My dropdowns]

[image: Display values where Type_abonnement = 0 for example]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to use JavaScript to achieve this.

There's hundreds of topics on this already, check out: [Populating a select box using JQUERY, AJAX and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991067/populating-a-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-and-php) for example.