# Getting value from HTML and use it as PHP var

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I have an `*<select>*` and the *`<option>`* are auto filled by database as the example below.

```
<?php include 'connection.php'; ?>
$query = "SELECT campo FROM apresentacaoservicos";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
<form name="form1" target="apresenta" method="POST" action="menu1.php">
<h6>Campo:</h6> 
<select name ="selected" id="selected" >
<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>
<option value="<?php echo $row1[0];?>"><?php echo $row1[0];?></option>
<?php endwhile;?>
</select>
```

Now I need to "**extract**" the value from selected option so I can use it as **PHP variable** so I can **query it (MySQL)**.

***Already tried :***

`*<select name="somethinghere">*` and use `*$_POST['somethinghere']*`
did not work.

I want to know if there is any way to do this by use `**document.getElementById("id").value**`or **other solution**

Comment: Need to use ajax with jquery if you intend to take anything from the html/javascript side and send it to a database WITHOUT submitting the form

Comment: To elaborate: JavaScript only starts running long after PHP has finished, so to get anything from the browser back to PHP, you need to communicate with the server again. The only way to do this without leaving the current page is to use AJAX / websockets.

Comment: @clearshot66 can u send me any SO question that have that ? I searched  and didnt find anything that works

Comment: Exact situation...first search option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991067/populating-a-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-and-php

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried getting it with the POST variable.  You named your select box "selected" in the code, so `$_POST['selected']` would give you the value of the selected option.  You have to submit the form to get that value.  That works.

Here's some simple code to post to the same page to get your data.

```
<?php   
echo"
<form action='"$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='cheese'>
<input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>
</form>";
if (isset($_POST['cheese'])) echo $_POST['cheese'];
?>
```

Comment: I dont want to submit the form I want to get it when click a button type button not submit

Comment: That would require AJAX which is something I don't know much about.  You could submit the form to itself, get the data you want from the post variable, then send it all to your menu1.php page.   That's how I usually do it.  Unless you absolutely don't want to have the page reload, then you need ajax.

Comment: how would u do that can u give me an example ?

Comment: In the form action, you can use `action='".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."'>`  Then you'll remain on the same page after the form submits.  and the value will be set in the post variable.  After you do what you want with the variable, you can redirect the page to menu1.php

Comment: I just added some simple code to show a self submitting form if you still need help.