# Adding options to dynamically generated select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am facing issues while adding the options in the `select` that I am generating dynamically using ***jQuery***. I am fetching options from the database and I want to show all those options for each dynamically generated `select` tag.

Please tell me what i am doing wrong in my code?

Here is my function to add new row :

```
function addnewrow() {
    var n = ($('.detail tr').length - 0) + 1;
    var tr = '<tr>' +
        '<td class="no">' + n + '</td>' +
        '<td><input type="checkbox" class="till_check" name="till_check[' + till_check_counter + ']" id="prdct_till_check[' + till_check_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><select class="form-control barcode  dyselect['+product_barcode_counter+']" name="barcode[' + product_barcode_counter + ']" id="prdct_barcode[' + product_barcode_counter + ']">'+'<option>Please select a bar code</option>'+'</select></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control productname"  id="brcode_product"  name="productname[' + product_name_counter + ']" id="prdct_name[' + product_name_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control sm" name="sm[' + sm_counter + ']" id="prdct_sm[' + sm_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control spl" name="spl[' + spl_counter + ']" id="prdct_spl[' + spl_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[' + product_quantity_counter + ']" id="prdct_qty[' + product_quantity_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price[' + product_price_counter + ']" id="prdct_price[' + product_price_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control discount" name="discount[' + product_discount_counter + ']" id="prdct_discount[' + product_discount_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control amount" name="amount[' + product_amount_counter + ']" id="prdct_amount[' + product_amount_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><a href="#" class="remove">Delete</td>' +
        '</tr>';
    $('.detail').append(tr);

    //incrementing the counter
    ++till_check_counter;
    ++product_name_counter;
    ++product_quantity_counter;
    ++sm_counter;
    ++spl_counter;
    ++product_price_counter;
    ++product_discount_counter;
    ++product_amount_counter;

    //setting the validation rules for every product attribute by calling the function 
    createValidation();
    get_barcodes();
}
```

Here is the function for getting barcodes from database :

```
function get_barcodes() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/retail/main/ajax_barcodes/',
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: {
      'barcode': $('#brcode option:selected').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
      /*var obj = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(obj.brcode.name);*/
      var myselect = $('.dyselect[' + product_barcode_counter + ']');
      var barcodes = JSON.parse(data);

      for (var i = 0; i < barcodes.brcode.length; i++) {
        //console.log(barcodes.brcode[i].name);
        //console.log(barcodes.brcode[i].barcode);

        var options = ('<option value="' + barcodes.brcode[i].barcode + '">' + barcodes.brcode[i].barcode + '</option>');
        console.log(options);
        // $('.dyselect['+product_barcode_counter+']').append("Hello world");

        $('.dyselect').text('dfsgfisdgfsiudfgsdf');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Please do not consider the commented code.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991067/populating-a-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-and-php

Answer (score 0):

You are not appending your options to the DOM anywhere.

```
myselect.append(options); // Missing this line
```

You are incrementing your `++product_barcode_counter` after adding a row

```
//incrementing the counter
++till_check_counter;
++product_name_counter;
++product_quantity_counter;
++sm_counter;
++spl_counter;
++product_price_counter;
++product_discount_counter;
++product_amount_counter;
```

so, by the time you are accessing the `product_barcode_counter` inside the ajax success its incremented.

Here, your

```
var myselect = $('.dyselect_' + product_barcode_counter);
```

selection is wrong it is returning nothing.

You have to bind your id to the ajax so that you can read the value on ajax success.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/retail/main/ajax_barcodes/',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: {
          'barcode': $('#brcode option:selected').val()
        },
        success: function(id,data) {
          //Here id is what you need to use to select the correct select.

       }.bind(this,product_name_counter-1)
 );
```

**JS**

```
function get_barcodes() {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/retail/main/ajax_barcodes/',
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: {
      'barcode': $('#brcode option:selected').val()
    },
    success: function(id,data) {
      var myselect = $('.dyselect_' + id);
      var barcodes = JSON.parse(data);


      for (var i = 0; i < barcodes.brcode.length; i++) {


        var options = ('<option value="' + barcodes.brcode[i].barcode + '">' + barcodes.brcode[i].barcode + '</option>');

        myselect.append(options); // Missing this line


      }


    }.bind(this,product_name_counter-1)
  });


}
```

OR you can use closure

```
success: (function(id){
     return function(data) {
          //Here id is what you need to use to select the correct select.
            }
 })(product_name_counter-1);
```

**JS**

```
function get_barcodes() {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/retail/main/ajax_barcodes/',
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: {
      'barcode': $('#brcode option:selected').val()
    },
    success: (function(id){
                 return function(data) {
                     var myselect = $('.dyselect_' + id);
                     var barcodes = JSON.parse(data);
                     for (var i = 0; i < barcodes.brcode.length; i++) {
                     var options = ('<option value="' + barcodes.brcode[i].barcode + '">' + barcodes.brcode[i].barcode + '</option>');

                     myselect.append(options); // Missing this line
                     }
                   }
               }
           })(product_name_counter-1);

     });
}
```

Comment: sorry i mistakenly remove this line before but i add again on console the options are showing correctly but it is not appending to the select tag that i am generating dynamically.

Comment: Thats because you are not appending your `myselect` also

Comment: var myselect = $('.dyselect[' + product_barcode_counter + ']');   is not a correct way?

Comment: no I am generating it dynamically in addnewrow() function  when i click on add button it adds on the page and also the options values fetched in ajax but it is not appending to the select tag that is generated dynamically.

Comment: You connot use `product_barcode_counter` its incremented after adding the row. you need to use `product_barcode_counter-1`

Comment: well I am generating multiple number of select tags that can be of any number and for all those select tags i want to append the options that i am fetching from the database through ajax request so i add the product_barcode_counter to keep the track of each select tag that is being added dynamically to the DOM .Also i add that variable because i am applying jquery validation to all those dynamically generated select tags. Am i doing something wrong with the code?

Comment: There is your problem you cannot select the filed using `product_barcode_counter` inside the ajax. As by the time your ajax success method is called the `product_barcode_counter` is already incremented

Comment: ohh i see then how i will keep the track of each select tag that is being added dynamically in the DOM ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value).bind is not a function

This is the console error now..!

Comment: Sorry, I binded in the wrong place. Check the update and I have also added another approach

Comment: remove `[` from `dyselect['+product_barcode_counter+']"` and use underscore instead `dyselect_'+product_barcode_counter` update your selector in ajax also

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .dyselect_

Comment: missing `'` in `.dyselect_'+product_barcode_counter` at the start add `'` `'.dyselect_'+product_barcode_counter`

Comment: @Nadir Laskar - I am developing a settings page of my site. In the form, there are some values which will be auto populated from the DB on page load. I did this using only PHP and also by ajax & PHP. In PHP, the values are loaded on the page load but in ajax, values are getting reflected only after the page load so I can see the default value for 2-3ms. Please suggest which is better way to use?