# Select a list to generate another list

Tags: javascript, java, php, mysql

Let's say I select one of the states in Nigeria, and I want it to give me a drop down containing list of local governments in that state, how do I go about it

Comment: I hope this will be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991067/populating-a-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-and-php

Comment: how can you get list of local governments in that state ? 
Do you have any table for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using AJAX. When a user change drop-down then call a AJAX function to get the list of local governments from your database based on item selected in your drop-down and display it.

Comment: Thank you sir, can I get a sample code from you...Thanks

Comment: for that you need to show some code so that i can suggest some modifications